# SQL - remove rows with more than one unique date against ID

Tags: sql

I'm trying to keep only rows where an ID has a single sales date, eg.

**ID SALES_DTE** 
101 10-Jan-12 
101 10-Jan-12 
101 10-Jan-12 
102 10-Jan-12 
102 13-Jan-12 
103 13-Jan-12

In the above, I want to keep IDs 101 and 103, because they only have one sales date. But I don't want 102 because it has two sales dates. Can anyone help?

Comment: `select * from mytable tb where not exists (select * from mytable nx where nx.id =tb.id and nx.sales_date <> tb.sales_date);` NB if you want to **physically remove them**: replace the "select *" by a "delete" **and remove the NOT**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete from your_table
where id not in 
(
   select id
   from your_table
   group by id
   having count(distinct sales_date) = 1
)
```

Comment: NOTE: this would also delete the tuples that happen to have `sales_date IS NULL` This may or may not be the intention of the OP.

Comment: That could be changed with the `having` clause: `having count(distinct sales_date) <= 1`